# Can I wrap tags around an element in CSS?

Tags: html, css, tags

For example, could I wrap all `<p>` elements in `<b>` tags so `<p>Hello</p>` would be rendered as if it were `<b><p>Hello</p></b>`?

I tried using `::before` and `::after` like this:

```css
p::before {
    content: "<b>";
}
p::after {
    content: "</b>";
}
```

but the tags were escaped. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: No; CSS is just for presentation; you'd need JavaScript for that purpose

Comment: to start with, a p element inside b won't be valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This would be a misuse of CSS. CSS is not designed to alter markup, but to augment it with styling. If you could do what you are suggesting, we developers would all be in a living hell.
You have some options:

### Option 1

- Wrap the content you want to make bold in a container
- Give that container a class
- Write a CSS class to make that container's content bold

e.g.
Original HTML

```
<html>
  <h1>My content<h1>
</html>
```

New HTML

```
<html>
   <section class="bold">
      <h1>My content<h1>
   </section>
</html>
<style>
.bold {
  font-weight: bold
}
</style>
```

### Option 2

- If you can't alter the markup
- Find a selector that will select the content you want
- Write a CSS class to make that container's content bold

```
<html>
  <h1>My content<h1>
</html>
<style>
h1:first-of-type { 
  font-weight: bold
}
</style>
```

Note the `:first-of-type` for an example of specificity selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `font-weight` property. Adding tags like this is not possible with CSS.

Example:

```
p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight).